# CanvasJS chart stop webpage when enable interactivityEnabled option

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, canvasjs

I am using CanvasJS chart for displying multiple stacked bar charts.
When I set `interactivityEnabled = true` to show tooltip, webpage not working suddenly.

```
animationEnabled: true,
colorSet: 'stackedBarColor',
theme: 'light1',
title: {
  text: 'Chart',
  fontSize: 15,
  fontWeight: 200,
  fontStyle: '500'
},
axisY: {
  interval: 10,
  suffix: '%'
},
toolTip: {
  shared: true
},
interactivityEnabled: false,
data: ChartData
```

This is config for chart.
What is the issue and how can solve it?

Comment: Not much of help, can you pls check the browser console or better make a working demo or something?

Comment: There is no any error in the browser console.

Comment: It seems to be working fine with the chart configuration that you have shared. Can you reproduce your use-case in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/QwZuf/) and share it - which would help understand your use-case better?